# Symfony2 get session in RegistrationFormType of FosUserBundle

Tags: php, session, symfony

I try to get the object session in my `RegistrationFormType` but I get this error : `Warning: Missing argument 2 for Meet\MembreBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType::__construct()`

My RegistrationFormType :

```
namespace Meet\MembreBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

    class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
    {
        private $session;
        public function __construct($session, $class)
        {
            $this->session = $session;
            parent::__construct($class);
        }

        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
        {
            parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
            $locale = $this->session->getLocale();
            var_dump($locale);

        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'meet_user_registration';
        }
    }
```

My config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    # Permet de renseigner la nouvelle entity utilisateur
    user_class: Meet\MembreBundle\Entity\Membre
    registration:
        form:
            type: meet_user_registration
services:
  meet_user_registration:
    class: Meet\MembreBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
    arguments: [@session, %fos_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: my_user_registration }
```

Comment: It is not question of session, it is question of missing `%fos_user.model.user.class%` parameter

Comment: How can i get the session object in my form ?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you forgot to define `%fos_user.model.user.class%` parameter

Did you follow [these steps](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle)?

Comment: I had already follow these steps, because FosUserBundle already works, how can i define fos_user.model.user.class ?

Comment: @user1364017 just in the `fos_user` section add `user_class: Meet\MembreBundle\Entity\User` or whatever you want ;)

Comment: meet_membre.registration.form.type: instead of meet_user_registration:
now it works